# How to suppress automatic quoting of strings with ruamel.yaml

Tags: yaml, ruamel.yaml

I am using ruamel.yaml to generate "recipes" for a build tool, which accepts a non-standard superset of yaml.  I'm getting some undesirable output, and my searches for how to disable this have come up dry.  Here's an example:

```
import ruamel.yaml as ryaml

test = ryaml.comments.CommentedMap(requirements={'host': ['abc', 'def   # [something]']})
print(ryaml.dump(test, Dumper=ryaml.RoundTripDumper,
                                            default_flow_style=False,
                                            default_style="",
                                            width=200))
```

This automatically quotes the thing that is not valid yaml (which honestly is quite sane default behavior):

```
requirements:
  host:
    - abc
    - 'def   # [something]'
```

I really need it to not add those single quotes around the non-standard line.  I don't expect ruamel to be able to parse it back in, just dump it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a plain scalar, but the `#` (whitespace followed by a hash) within that scalar could be interpreted as a comment. Therefore that scalar needs to be quoted to be represented correctly. The same would happen if you had `:` (colon + whitespace).

The only thing you can do is change the value to e.g. `'def   _# [something]'`

This restriction on plain scalars is [clearly documented in the specification](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788859).

(You can of course generate commented YAML with `ruamel.yaml`, if that is  your intention. But you **cannot** do that by simplisticly including a comment in a value: there would be no way to distinguish that from a real value that includes the characters space+hash)

Comment: I think that we are far enough off of the reservation that we just can't use ruamel.yaml to dump here.  We have other things like jinja2 variables that also get this treatment, so I think we'll just have to have a crappy hack approach.  Thanks for the info, anyway!

Comment: Adding comments from scratch is doable but non-trivial. If you can start with a template and just add some key-value pairs to mappings and elements to sequences. That way comments in the template remain in the dump. There is also round-tripping for `jinja2` as an [extension](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml.jinja2/) with which you can do similar things (but not trivially adding new `jinja2` constructs.

Comment: The other thing I have successfully applied to get things that `ruamel.yaml` cannot output as I wanted, e.g. if the indentation had to be valid, but inconsistent. Is to output some special character sequences and replace those while dumpiing.

Comment: Both good ideas.  I ended up writing a crappy recursive string builder, but if/when that inevitably isn't enough, I'll revisit this with your ideas.